# file_usage_add: custom type for my module

Tags: 7, files

I have a custom calendar module I've created. When a user creates an event they have the ability to attach a thumbnail image to it. I'm trying to make it use the managed_file type. In the documentation it appears I need to use file_usage_add to keep it from throwing an error. The problem is I'm not sure what to put in the 'type' and 'id' parameters. The documentation lists these required parameters:

- $file: A file object.
- $module: The name of the module using the file.
- $type: The type of the object that contains the referenced file.
- $id: The unique, numeric ID of the object containing the referenced file.

$file and $module are easy. However, this module doesn't create a node or anything else. I have my own table structure for this information. Is there a way to define my table that events get stored in as a 'type' and pass that with the unique id from that table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `type` just needs to be something unique within *your module's* types of file usage. The value of the string itself is arbitrary.

So if you have a module which stores pictures of cats and dogs, and you want to address those two different types of usage separately, you might use (contrived examples obviously):

```
$cat = MYMODULE_load_cat('whiskers');
file_usage_add($file, 'MYMODULE', 'cat_pictures', $cat->id);

$dog = MYMODULE_load_dog('fido');
file_usage_add($file, 'MYMODULE', 'dog_pictures', $dog->id);
```

But the `type` for those could just as easily be `cat_foo` and `dog_foo`, all that matters is that you (the module developer) know what they are, so they can be used appropriately with `file_usage_delete()`.

Comment: Thanks. Where do you define the type though? Since it has to have an id I'm assuming I have to declare this object class type somewhere.

Comment: Oh, never mind. I see what you're saying. In my case I would just use a constant type, say 'event_thumb'. then in the id I would give it the id for my event that the thumbnail is attached to, say $event->id. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, exactly right

Comment: Sorry, I have the same problem (more or less) and I don't understand the answer in the comment: what should I use for 'id'? Something random? The session id? There is no node yet, so I can't use a node-id?

Comment: I am creating a custom form with a file upload option. Its just a stand-alone form. What do I mention for 'id'?

Comment: @SupriyaRajgopal If you don't have a serial number available naturally, you need to create one. Maybe keep a variable in storage that you increment each time you perform this operation